Is there a way to write SKILL script where LVS report file (generated in .lvs.report ) can be written to .csv file
Is there a way to write SKILL script where LVS report file (generated in .lvs.report ) can be written to .csv file ?
I am trying to write a SKILL script wherein I can copy the lvs.report file data to .csv file
I want to firstly read the file and then copy the data to a .csv file
I tried using inPort to read the file but it doesnt seem to work.

You can definitely read and write files using SKILL. Tomorrow, when I am at work, I will add examples of how to do it.

Thanks Alex , that would be of great help for me if you demonstrate with added examples.

To read a file you can do something like this:
inPort = infile( "filename" )
while( gets( nextLine inPort )
    printf("%s" nextLine)
)
close(inPort)

To write a file you can do:
op=outfile("filename" "w")
fprintf(op "%s %s\n" net1 net2)
close(op)


